# Goal Strength parameter in "Soft Body Goal" works differently in 2.76+ versions

Tags: physics, soft-body

I learn soft body physics in Blender and tried to perform a lesson from tutorial: creating soft-body plane with "pins" on edge vertexes (like hammock). But when i play the animation, result was very different from  described in tutorial. Lesson was written for Blender 2.71, and first thing i repeat experiment in this version. And all worked properly. I tryed different versions and found what in 2.76 parameter "Soft Body Goal > Goal Strength" greatly changed its influence on animation. But i haven't found this change in "New Feature" description or "Bug Fixes" list. So, my question: it's a "bug" or "bug fix" in versions after 2.75 (2.76, 2.77, 2.78)? I would be grateful if anybody would give a link where i can read about this change. On screenshots 25 frame of animation this soft-body object in 2.75 and 2.78 versions.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the vertex group weight painted the same in both versions?

Comment: Yes, the vertex group weight painted the same. The file was created in 2.75, saved and opened in both versions for screenshots. If create such an object in 2.76-77-78  - effect like on bottom screenshot, If then save file and open in 2.75 (or below) - animation looks like on 1st image, slight fluctuations, almost flat. All settings in all fields by default.

Comment: im thinking its worth reporting a bug https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/